# If statement to check if user is deleting cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba and I am running into a `Type mismatch` error when I delete multiple cells in my workbook, and it is failing at the `If` statement here:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value = "Multiple Choice - Multiple Answer" Then
        MsgBox "You selected MC-MA"
    End If
End Sub
```

**I am wondering if there's a way to check if a user is deleting contents of a cell and NOT run this if statement if that is the case?**

I have tried `If Trim(Target.Value) <> Empty` but it throws the error I'm guessing because Im trying to run an If statement on a value that doesn't exist.

I expect `If Trim(Target.Value) <> Empty` to make it skip the above code but it throws the `Type mismatch` error.

Answer (score 1):

**Try the `SelectionChange` Event like this:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In Target
    If cel.Value = "Multiple Choice - Multiple Answer" Then
        MsgBox "You selected MC-MA"
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

- In `Change` event even if you try and check cells one by one, you won't spot the cell with that match because ***the code runs after the delete has been executed***. So by the time it comes to the If statement, the cell is already blank.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem with this is I need it to happen only if there is a change in the cell. I failed to mention that the cell is a dropdown list and if they select "Multiple Choice - Multiple Answer" in that cell, I want the code to run. The only problem with my code is if someone deletes a group of cells anywhere in the sheet it will throw the error. And I want them to be able to delete cells.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way around it. If I just do an If statement that checks `if Target.Count = 1` then run the code it works!